# Conditional link display in desktop view

Tags: html, css

I have a site where users can choose to create a link to their own website. In mobile view, when a user has chosen not to display a website, the background color for this link, as well as the word itself, is not visible.

In desktop, however, it is.

When a user lists a site, it displays 'visit website' with background color, when they don't, in mobile the link 'visit website' and background-color disappears but in desktop, whilst the word 'visit-website' disappears, the background-color doesn't.

So it appears some kind of conditional logic is working for mobile view, but not desktop.

I don't even know where to find the code which dictates this.

Im assuming I can't do css @media query to rectify?

Comment: Hi Ads and welcome to SO, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and or see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you use the inspector you should be able to locate the problematic code and insert into a snippet here.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your message. What is ' the inspector'? Can provide you with page link? https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-service/london/uk/westminster/business-advert/

Comment: Here is page where background to link doesn't display in mobile but does in desktop. https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/21/old-goriot-balzac/london/uk/westminster/books/

Comment: I suggest you use [Chrome Devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) to spot the misbehaving code.

Comment: The background to your link appears both in Mobile and Desktop mode (it is simply hidden under another link in Mobile view). You should style the link instead of the container `.visit-website`

Answer (score -1):

Not seeing the code, I assume that you can use @media query to rectify the css. It sure sounds like it.

Comment: Don't you have the source code? I'm confused? If not check console.log perhaps using Chrome and check the mobile responsivity. It should show the mobile css if there is one.

Comment: How do i do this please?

Comment: F12, then go to the phone icon next to elements